# Textarea required field is not working after using javascript text editor

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made `textarea` as required field, it was working fine until I used the below `javascript` code to make it as `texteditor`

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/nicEdit_without_img.js'); ?>"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    nicEditors.editors.push(
        new nicEditor().panelInstance(
            document.getElementById('txt_job_description')
        )
    );
});
```

Html code, when I click submit button with values, its still asking to fill the required text area, and that's the problem.

```
<textarea class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="txt_desired_skills" id="txt_desired_skills" value="" required><?php echo $txt_desired_skills;?></textarea>
```

Comment: you should better use jquery to validate your textarea `var textarea = $("div.nicEdit-main").html();`

Comment: check the class or id with editor